# PHP Not Sending to email account

Tags: php, email

Yes, I've already read everything I can on here about "my php isn't sending email" and it doesn't help my issue.

I have looked and looked over this PHP script and I finally got it to where it says "mail sent" and sends it to my thank-you.html. But, I never actually receive the email. Can someone please help? :/

```
 <?php
print_r($_POST);
//die;
$field_name = $_POST['name'];
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$field_message = $_POST['message'];
$field_option = $_POST['option'];
$field_number = $_POST['number'];
$field_choice = $_POST['choice'];

$mail_to = 'tbcoh5091@gmail.com';
$subject = 'A prayer form has been submitted by '.$field_name;

$body_message .= 'Option: '.$field_option."\n";
$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Number: '.$field_number."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message."\n";
$body_message .= 'Choice: '.$field_choice;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail('tbcoh5091@gmail.com', $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.location = 'thank-you.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, go back and try again.');
        window.location = 'prayer-and-praise.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Please help me if at all possible! Thank you. If I need to post my HTML part of my form, here's that.

```
<form action="email.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="tbcoh5091@gmail.com" / >
            <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="From the Prayer form" / >
            <p>Is this going to be a Prayer, Praise, or both?</p>
            <input type="radio" name="option" value="Prayer"> Prayer
            <input type="radio" name="option" value="Praise"> Praise
            <input type="radio" name="option" value="Both"> Both
            <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
            <p>First and Last Name</p>
            <input type="text" name="name" size="60">
            <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
            <p>Email Address</p>
            <input type="text" name="email" size="60">
            <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
            <p>Phone Number (optional)</p>
            <input type="text" name="number" size="10">
            <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
            <p>Your Message</p>
            <textarea name="message" rows="9" cols="60"></textarea>
            <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
            <p>Last but not least, please indicate if you would like for this to stay personal, or sent out to congregation.</p>
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value="personal"> Personal
            <input type="radio" name="choice" value="sent_out"> Send to Congregation
            <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" value="Reset">
            </form>
```

Comment: Have check other message folder? like spam folder?

Comment: Are you doing this on your machine? If so, do you have a mail server set up? And the ports needed forwarded?

Comment: `$body_message .= 'Option: '.$field_option."\n";
$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";`  switch those two. It's breaking the chain, *as it were*.

Comment: swap those two and that's it?!?!

Comment: Far as I can tell, yes; try it. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: now it won't even pop up the "thank-you.html"

it does nothing now.

Comment: all i did was swap those too, and now it won't even send me to the thank-you.html. (and i added that line) did i do something else wrong?